# Best method for connecting to sustom XML web service in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services

What is the best way to work with/consume custom XML web services in ASP.NET?  The web service in question was developed quite a few years ago.  It works by POST'ing the XML to a specific web page and then responding with more XML.  Run of the mill design, but it doesn't follow any SOAP standards.  It follows a strict schema though.

What technologies are out there now that can make working with this easier?  Or am I stuck doing custom HTTPRequests?

Answer (score 1):

I've hear great things of [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) and I think it can easily cover your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your web service is a "XML over HTTP" Service. I think you may end up doing custom HTTP Posts as they are not at all standardized.

Answer (score 0):

I would bite the bullet and convert it to a known standard such as SOAP, JSON...etc.  You have so many tools in .NET to make the consumptions brainless if you use a standard.  You will probably encounter less bugs going forward as well.